# Read / write hardwares values for FSUIPC (module for FS)

Tags: serial, atmega, communication, hardware, simulation

I'm building an auto-pilot module for FSX (flight simulator) with push buttons and rotary encoders. My micro is one ATmega88. My question is how I do the communication with FSUIPC (software to read and write assignments to simulator) and my hardware? I'm going to use a serial communication to PC. I have to use a program to read and write values but how do I get these values for FSUIPC?

PS: I have SDK for FSUIPC (language C)...

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the ATMega88 and pick a part that has USB, such as an ATMega16U4. Use HID and enumerate it as a joystick what sufficient buttons. Make each button a button, and two buttons per rotary encoder. Then use FSUIPC to assign button presses to the actual key commands.